# Extended bottom edge diagonally,

Tags: css, forms

I'm trying to create this effect (screen) for input field in the search form.
The idea is for a diagonal line to appear at the end.

I have absolutely no idea how I can achieve it.

Now I have the usual bottom border, I think a good solution would be to add a pseudo-class element: after and then rotate by 45*. Do I mean right?

```
#searchform input[type="text"]{
  border:none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #271010;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 188px;
  position: relative;
}
```

[what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uJ83.png)

[what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFT1o.png)

Comment: Unfortunately putting a pseudo element on an input is not in general within the spec, see for example, discussion and explanation here [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could play around with linear gradient backgrounds to achieve roughly that effect.

```css
#searchform input[type="text"]{
  --color: #eeeeee;
  border:none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 188px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, var(--color), var(--color)), linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, var(--color) 48%, var(--color) 52%, transparent 52%, transparent);
  background-size: 80% 1.5px, 20% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: left bottom, 91% bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchform"><input type="text"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good way to solve this +1